# Artisan publish Sanctum without a migration file

Tags: php, laravel, sanctum

- Sanctum Version: 2.15
- Laravel Version: 9.11
- PHP Version: 8.0.2
- Database Driver & Version:  mysql

#### Description:

I publish Sanctum did not generate the configuration

#### Steps To Reproduce:

The Laravel Sail development environment was used

- into the shell and perform

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Sanctum\SanctumServiceProvider"`

- prompt

`Copied Directory [/vendor/laravel/sanctum/database/migrations] To [/database/migrations] Publishing complete.`

- But there are no migration files generated under my migrations directory

Later, I checked the directory permission and found no problem.
Although it can be added manually, I still want to know where this problem can be investigated, because I did not see it mentioned in the document

Comment: It could be that the migrations are already present in the migrations folder. Please check if there is the <date>_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table.php file is present in there

Comment: It is true that the project contains this file by default. I never noticed the file name because its full name is  '2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table.php'   the 2019 in front of it, so I ignored it .
  Thank you very much David !